# Azure Application Insights how to determine where traffic spikes are coming from

Tags: azure-application-insights

We have an app service (website) that is getting hammered every 15 minutes with requests that make it fire up 5 services to handle the traffic.

How do we determine the geolocation and ips of the requests that are hitting it the most?

Comment: Since this is an administration related question, you may have better luck asking it on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for ips, Application insights does not store real ips by default(it stores the ip as 0.0.0.0). And if you want to collect ips, please follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-collection).

> How do we determine the geolocation and ips of the requests that are
>   hitting it the most?

An easiest way, you can write [Kusto query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview) in azure portal(assume you can collect the ips / locations like city or country), and add some [where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/whereoperator) clauses to filter / use [summarize operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator) and [sort operateor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sortoperator) to check the results. Here is a simple query:

[image]